# Bootstrap navbars form

Tags: java, html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

I copy-pasted a bootstrap nav and added it into my partials folder. I include this partial in every ejs file that i render.
The problem is that the form and the button are stacked one on another like this:

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VKzD.png)

What am i doing wrong?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I just copied & pasted your code , Its working fine for me.
So I believe might be some other css is impacting your view. or might be version of bootstrap. I am using bootstrap 4.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some mistakes. I have made a snippet for you. Have a look.

Thanks me later.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group my-0">
      <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-0 ml-2" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

Comment: i literally copy and pasted it... i have partials that include bootstrap too

Comment: What do you mean by you have partials

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the button does not wrap, I suggest using [`.input-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons) as follows:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success input-group-text" type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</nav>
```